# Close curves on an Andrews plot

Tags: data-visualization, multivariate-analysis

On the [Andrews plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrews_plot), close points (that is inputs) appear as close functions (the curves), but the reverse does not necessarily hold. That is there can be two curves on the Andrews plot that are close, but the original points are far away. Is this correct? If yes, and as an aid to understanding, how to mathematically create input points that are distant but whose Andrews' curves are close?

Comment: Trivium on a detail that many people with English as first language often struggle with. The person named is the Toronto statistician David Andrews. Andrews plot and Andrews' plot are both common and defensible forms, but Andrew's plot is not good English The same minor issue arises with ideas of Colin Mallows, Harold Jeffreys, S.S. Wilks and others whose family name ends with "s".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you take cross correlation as measure for distance between curves

For the [curves in the Andrews plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrews_plot)

$$f_x(t) = x_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + x_2 \sin(t) + x_3 \cos(t) + x_4 \sin(2t)+ ...$$

The cross covariance

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f_x(t) f_y(t) dt$$

can be simplified as separate products (because the trigonometric functions are orthogonal)

$$ x_1 y_1 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} dt + x_2 y _2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(t) \sin(t) dt + x_3 y_3 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(t) \cos(t) dt + ...$$

and this is the covariance between the vectors

$$  x_1y_1 \pi + x_2y_2 \pi + x_3y_3 \pi + ... = \pi \vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}$$

*See also [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) and [orthonormal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality)*

---

It is a bit tricky, the definitions of cross variance and cross correlation. Of course you need to see the difference relative to the size of the vectors. If the vectors are larger then the difference and the covariance will be larger. So you need to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalization) the functions and then you can make the same argument/computations for correlation as for covariance above.

Thus if the vectors/points have a high correlation (are close together) then the curves will have a high cross correlation as well (close together).

This works in *both* ways.

---

#### If you take the mean absolute difference as measure.

In this case it will be more or less the same

$$\small\begin{array}{}
\overbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f_y(t)-f_x(t)|dt}^{\text{mean absolute difference}}&\leq&\overbrace{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f_y(t)-f_x(t))^2dt}}^{\text{root mean squared difference}} =\\
&\leq&\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_x(t)^2dt+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_y(t)^2dt-\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_x(t)f_y(t)dt} \end{array}$$

but in this case it goes in one way and due to the inequality it is possible to have a small mean absolute difference while the root mean squared difference is large.

The inequality is stronger when the difference $f_y(t)-f_x(t)$ is less homogeneously spaced.

- The equality occurs when only $x_1 \neq y_1$ and for all other $i \neq 1$ we have $x_i = y_i$. (because then the difference $f_y(t)-f_x(t)$ is constant and the mean absolute difference equals the root mean squared distance)
- In case for some $j>1$ we have $x_j \neq y_j$ and all other $i \neq j$ we have $x_i = y_i$ then we have for the $\sin(kt)$ case with integer values of $k$ (and the same for the $\cos(kt)$ case)

  $$\small\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f_y(t)-f_x(t)|dt = (y_j-x_j) \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \vert \sin(kt) \vert dt = (y_j-x_j) \frac{2}{\pi} \approx 0.637$$

  whereas

  $$\small\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f_y(t)-f_x(t))^2dt} = (y_j-x_j) \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \sin(kt)^2 dt} = (y_j-x_j) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.707$$

  This is independent from from the particular coordinate. It is the same for all $sin(kt)$ or $cos(kt)$
- For combinations of coordinates that are different you will have to work it out a bit. I am not sure whether you can get extremely large differences between the mean absolute difference and the root mean squared difference, but in general the inequality may be somewhat larger than the two cases above. For example:

  $$\small\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \vert 0.5+ 0.5\sin(t) \vert dt = \frac{1}{2} = 0.500$$

  $$\small\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (0.5+ 0.5\sin(t))^2 dt} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}} \approx 0.612$$

Comment: This seems to answer the question. I previously thought that close curves are still possible for distant points, but you have shown that close Andrews' curves implies close input vectors - is this understanding correct? Suppose we measure the distance between two curves as the integral of the absolute value of one curve subtracted from another. Would this integral's value be proportional to the absolute value of the cross-covariance? I ask this to ensure I have understood everything.

Comment: The difference between two vectors will be smaller if the correlation between the vectors is larger. $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f_y(t)-f_x(t)|dt\leq\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f_y(t)-f_x(t))^2dt}\\=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_x(t)^2dt+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_y(t)^2dt-2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_x(t)f_y(t)dt}$$ so indeed the mean absolute value of the difference of the curves will relate to the correlation between points. This is however not directly proportional and it is like the inequality on the left, the root of the mean of the square is not the same as the mean of the absolute value, but in general they are similar

Comment: The understanding is correct. Close curves will relate to close points (and vice versa). It is however possible that curves are close *only in a particular small region* and far away outside the region. Maybe that is what you had in mind?

Comment: The inequality you provide here is excellent, and it links the simple concept of absolute differences to the cross-variance, of which the latter you have already shown that close inputs if and only if close outputs (Andrews' curves). My initial comment was wrong, it should have been that a small absolute difference integral will occur if and only if the cross-variance is large and positive. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: On your second comment, the kind of example I thought this would occur is say you had two identical inputs of four dimensions and then on one of the inputs you made the "last" dimension differ by a relatively large amount (the one that is multiplied by sin(2t) in your formula above) then the resulting curves could still be close. I had thought that the "last" (right-most) dimensions as input into the Andrews' cuve affect the output less than dimensions with a lower t multiple in the cosine or sine input.

Comment: *" My initial comment was wrong, it should have been that a small absolute difference integral will occur if and only if the cross-variance is large and positive."* Because of the inequality the 'iff' is not correct. If 'root mean square' is small than 'mean absolute value' is small, but the other way around is not necessary. But I guess that your understanding is correct. Keep in mind the tricky difference of cross-variance and cross-correlation. It is relative. Without [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalization) high (cross) variance can mean high distance.

Comment: *" I had thought that the "last" (right-most) dimensions as input into the Andrews' cuve affect the output less than dimensions with a lower t multiple in the cosine or sine input"* Each of the terms has the same effect on the distance in terms of the *root mean square error*. Check out [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) and [orthonormal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality)

Comment: Understood both responses. Finally, what is the name of the well-known inequality above?

Comment: @SingleMalt To be honest, I am no sure whether $MAE \leq RMSE$ has a specific name. But you could derive it with the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), by expressing a function $f(t)$ as a sum of two components: the mean of that function and the variation relative to the mean $f(t) = \mu_f + \delta_f(t)$

$$\Vert \mu_f +\delta_f(t) \Vert \leq \Vert \mu_f \Vert + \Vert \delta_f(t) \Vert =  \Vert \mu_f \Vert$$

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus what do you mean by "normalizing" the functions $f_x$ and $f_y$?