# Cross-covariance in context of Andrews plot

Tags: covariance, cross-correlation, projection, orthogonal

As shown in this Cross-Validated post
[Close curves on an Andrews plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465070/close-curves-on-an-andrews-plot)

I don't understand how, in the accepted answer, the cross-covariance can be defined as,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_xf_ydt$$
Considering the Andrews plot which states, for $d$-dimensional data $x \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times d}$,
$$f_x(t) = \sum_{i=1}^d x_i \phi_i(t)$$
for $\phi_i$ as per the usual finite Fourier series, if one choses all $\phi_i$ to be orthonormal instead, the expression becomes
$$\int_{T}f_xf_ydt = x \cdot y$$
where $(\cdot)$ is the dot-product. Does anyone here have a source of explanation or similar? I have searched the web for quite a while but clearly I am not asking the correct question in the search-engine, so I am asking here, appreciating all answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's the right track but I can't see it for now, do you recommend any source in this topic? i.e. in statistical context

Comment: Edit: nevermind I found it.